# SKLearn linear regression - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to do a linear regression with sklearn and create a coefficients and p-values table

this is the code I'm using

```
    y = df['Result']
    x = df['Pts actual']
    y = y.values.reshape(-1,1)
    x = x.values.reshape(-1,1)
    reg = LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(x,y)
    reg.coef_
    reg.intercept_
    f_reg_p_val = f_regression(x,y)[1]
    reg_summary = pd.DataFrame(data = x.columns.values, columns=['Features'])
    reg_summary['p-values'] = f_reg_p_val
    reg_summary
```

Whereas I select only one column from the original dataframe out of 10 as feature in x

At the line

```
    reg_summary = pd.DataFrame(data = x.columns.values, columns=['Features'])
```

I get this error

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-276-786cf89afda3> in <module>
    ----> 1 reg_summary = pd.DataFrame(data = x.columns.values, columns=['Features'])
          2 #reg_summary['coefficients'] = reg.coef_
          3 reg_summary['p-values'] = f_reg_p_val
          4 reg_summary
    
    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted your dataframe into a `numpy` array on this line:

```
x = x.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

The `x.values` part returns a `numpy` array, which doesn't have a `columns` attribute. That's why the code later throws an `AttributeError` when you try to access `x.columns`—it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, of course, otherwise I'd have x and y with shape (n,) and I'd get an error when performing the regression
 
`Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample`

Comment: What's your question, then?

Comment: my question is how do i get to create the summary table having x with only one feature

Comment: You want to just show the feature values, not the feature weights (coefficients)? Then why not just use `DataFrame(data=x, columns=['Features'])` on the crashing line?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get a table showing the feature weights